# ClassNotFoundException inside Google-Analytics from inside Google-Play-Services

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services

I got a strange crash in my app and the new Analytics from inside Google-Play-Services - this bug seems to be really rare, but I really would like to know what is going on there.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.analytics.tracking.android.AnalyticsReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.analytics.tracking.android.AnalyticsReceiver" on path: /mnt/asec/org.ligi.passandroid-1/pkg.apk
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2375)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.analytics.tracking.android.AnalyticsReceiver" on path: /mnt/asec/org.ligi.passandroid-1/pkg.apk
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2370)
    ... 10 more
```